# Override the error message Unable to resolve host “<insert URL here>” No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android

I'm using retrofit for making post server call. when my web server is off. I got message like **`Unable to resolve host "<insert URL here>": No address associated with hostname`**. I want to want to `toast` user readable error message like **Server is not reachable**. I want to know how to do that. following are some relevant code.

```
mEasyRetrofit.setPostMethod(WebConstants.CONTACT_FAMILY_LIST_URL, map, hashmap, new WebserviceCallBack() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response, int code) {
        // Some code
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Object response, int code) {
        if (response instanceof String) {
            String str_failure = (String) response;
            CustomToast.animRedTextMethod(getBaseActivity(), "" + str_failure, true);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to overcome your problem:

```
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Object response, int code) {
            if (response instanceof String) {
              //  String str_failure = (String) response;
                CustomToast.animRedTextMethod(getBaseActivity(), "Server is not reachable" , true);

                // OR simple Add
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),  "Server is not reachable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
```